# Confused about .join()

Tags: python

I’m new to python and completely confused,

why `','.join('a','b','c')`rised an error, a `",".join(['a','b','c'])`didn’t.

Why the code below have the same output?

```
In [3]: ",".join({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3})
Out[3]: 'b,a,c'

In [4]: ",".join({'a':2,'b':1,'c':3})
Out[4]: 'b,a,c'

In [5]: ",".join({'a':3,'b':2,'c':1})
Out[5]: 'b,a,c'
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant to put: `','.join(('a', 'b', 'c'))` for your first join example which would be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` takes only one argument of the iterable type. `','.join('a','b','c')`gives join 3 arguments of type string instead of 1. Whereas `",".join(['a','b','c'])` gives join only 1 argument of type list which is an iterable. Single or double quotes make no difference.

For your second question, all 3 dictionaries give the same output since what value is stored for a key makes no difference. So whether a key has a value of 1 or 3 or perhaps some string, it wont affect the order. The order of a dictionary is inherently arbitrary. It cannot be predicted in advance and it is because of the fact how dictionaries are stored in memory.

Answer (score 5):

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) on `str.join` state that the method takes **an** `iterable` which is any type that can be iterated over (list, tuple, etc.):

> `str.join(iterable)¶`
>
> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable. A `TypeError` will be raised if there are any non-string values in iterable, including bytes objects. The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

---

In your first example, you pass three arguments to a method which expects one so receive a `TypeError`, whereas you use the method as intended in the example where you pass a list (indicated so through the use of square brackets). In your typed examples, you are passing dictionaries which are also iterable, however, when iterated over, they yield their keys (note: the order is undetermined). So the keys of say: `{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}` are: `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` and since these are all strings, the method works fine to join them together with a comma

Comment: @user18861 since your new to Python here's more on iterables: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators.

Answer (score 3):

Because with `','.join('a','b','c')`, you're providing **3 arguments**, each of which is a `str`, to `str.join()`, which is unexpected (expected 1).

With `','.join(['a','b','c'])`, you're providing only **1 argument** which is a `list`, and it works well.